# Remove Time From Date Time field on POS Receipt in Odoo 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, point-of-sale

[image: Need to remove time from pos ticket]

**Need to remove time from pos ticket**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Way.
Check the link[Click Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/js/models.js#L2301) from there you can inherit js on your app and change the format **DateTime** to **date**.

Like this - **field_utils.format.date(moment(this.validation_date), {}, {timezone: false});**

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant code behind that link. A quote from "how do i write a good answer" from the help center: Provide context for links.
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @CZoellner Thanks for such nice advice. I'll make sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

For Referring

```
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
var field_utils = require('web.field_utils');



var _super_order = models.Order.prototype;
models.Order = models.Order.extend({

    initialize_validation_date: function () {
        _super_order.initialize_validation_date.apply(this,arguments);
        this.validation_date = new Date();
        this.formatted_validation_date = field_utils.format.date(
            moment(this.validation_date), {}, {timezone: false});

           },


        });
```